# Get closest datetime index value from pd DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got following DataFrame:

```
                                  holdings
2021-08-28 04:10:14.130412+00:00  {'$USD': 158, 'Apple': 3}
2021-08-25 18:10:14.130412+00:00  {'$USD': 158, 'Apple': 3}
```

With holdings as column and datetimes as index.

I got this by converting following dict to a DataFrame: (data is not consistent with previous example but it is the same format, so please ignore that)

```
{
    datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 28, 4, 10, 15, 180064, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc): {
        "$USD": "158.1727087865",
        "Apple": "3",
        "MSFT": "3",
    },
    datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 4, 10, 15, 180064, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc): {
        "$USD": "158.1727087865",
        "Apple": "3",
        "MSFT": "3",
    }
}
```

I transform the dict to a dataframe by:

```
    holdings_dict = {
        key: {"holdings": holdings_dict[key]}
        for key in holdings_dict.keys()
    }
    holdings_df =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        holdings_dict, orient="index", columns=["holdings"]
    ).sort_index(axis=0)
```

Now I try to get the nearest index and value to a certain date, let's say 2021-08-25, which is stored as cur_datetime

```
holdings_df.index.get_loc(
                    pd.to_datetime(cur_datetime), method="previous"
                )["holdings"]
```

But this gives an error

```
ValueError: Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill), backfill (bfill) or nearest. Got previous
```

How can I get the value of the nearest datetime (in a query you would do this by LTE)

Comment: Based on the error message, what happens if you use `method='nearest'`, or `method='ffill'`? (Reference for `method` argument: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say you have a bit unconventional way to work with pandas ;)

Nevertheless, `get_loc` return the range, so you need to use `iloc` to slice your row:

```
holdings_df.iloc[holdings_df.index.get_loc(pd.to_datetime(cur_datetime), method='backfill')]['holdings']
```

output:

```
{'$USD': '158.1727087865', 'Apple': '3', 'MSFT': '3'}
```

Comment: any better way to get the same output with pandas?